# ASP 4.0, C# Writing a DataSet as XML Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, xml, dataset

I am simply trying to load a dataset and output it on a webpage as XML with the schema being written as well. I have been researching to find a way to achieve this without any luck.

The code I am using is:

```
string str =
     "SELECT Name,Members,MaxLvl,Faction,Government,Score FROM dim5orgs where faction =
    'Omni' order by Score DESC";

// Connection string for a typical local MySQL installation
string cnnString = "Server=xxxxxxxnet;Port=3306;Database=xxx;Uid=xxxxx;Pwd=xxxx";

// Create a connection object and data adapter
MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

// Create a SQL command object
string cmdText = str;

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnx);

// Create a fill a Dataset
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
adapter.Fill(ds);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
ds.WriteXml(sw,XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
string result = sw.ToString();

Response.Write(result);
```

Right now I am getting output like:

```
Punk732220OmniRepublic1644786805740

Paradise754220OmniDepartment1633903815782
```

I would like the output to be in proper XML form somehow using the column names in the dataset.

Like:

```
<data>
    <name>Punk</name>
    <members>732</members>
    <Maxlvl>220</MaxLvl>...etc 
</data>
```

I would like to be in proper XML form, with the XML headers written properly.

Thank you.

Comment: Michael, did either of the answers below answer your question - if one of them did, could you mark it as accepted please?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I am getting output like", does that mean you are seeing that in your webpage, or that is what "result" contains when you debug the program?

If the former, you are probably missing setting the response type:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

and optionally the encoding:

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

before you write your response.

**EDIT:** Also, make sure you are not returning any html from your page template or master page (assuming you are using .aspx files). You can check this by looking at your page source in your browser (right click and "view source" in IE). Apologies if this teaching you to suck eggs, from your question I didn't know if you have already checked these things or not.

Edit 2: I've tested your code, and if you set the response `ContentType` to text/xml it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the documentation of the [XmlSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer%29;k%28XmlSerializer%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true). I think you could use it something like this:

```
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileLocation);

XmlSerializer xml = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ds.GetType());
xml.Serialize(streamWriter, ds);

streamWriter.Close();
```

I have not tried it with DataSets so I'm not sure.